# amend original data with cluster indices

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am using this toy code to perform some basic hierarchical clustering:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

OrginalData <- read.table("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Somewhere/IrisTabSepData/IrisData.txt",
                   header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

SubsetData <- subset(OrginalData, select = c(
#"SepalLength"
#,"SepalWidth"
"PetalLength"
,"PetalWidth"
))

clusters = hclust(dist(SubsetData), method = 'average')
plot(clusters)

clusterCut <- cutree(clusters, 3)
table(clusterCut, OrginalData$Species)

ggplot(OrginalData, aes(PetalLength, PetalWidth, color = OrginalData$Species)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4, size = 3.5) + geom_point(col = clusterCut) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'red', 'green'))
```

Is it possible to add an additional column to the original dataframe OrginalData which contains the clusters created in the above code (3 in this case 1-3) and write it as csv file?

Comment: `OriginalData$clusterCut = clusterCut` 
`write.csv(OriginalData, "EnhancedIris.csv", row.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks this works great. There were a few spelling mistakes so here is the working code: OrginalData$clusterCut = clusterCut 
write.csv(OrginalData, "EnhancedIris.csv", row.names=FALSE). Would you be happy to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `clusterCut` that you already created contains the clusters. You can simply add them to the data.frame and use `write.csv` to save off the data.

```
OrginalData$clusterCut = clusterCut 
write.csv(OrginalData, "EnhancedIris.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```