# Exporting data from R after getting results

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Could someone help me in this problem
I’m working on clustering a data and after i got the clustering results , I would like to export each cluster data on a single "csv" file is there a simple and efficient way to do It in this case.

[image]

this is the code I've used to generate the dendogram

```
   library(leaflet)
   library(sp)
   mydata<-read.csv("new.csv")
   View(mydata)
   mydata<-mydata[complete.cases(mydata),]
   tableau <- data.frame(x=mydata[,7],y=mydata[,8]);plot(tableau)
   mydi = dist(tableau[,],method= "euclidean")
   myclust <- hclust(mydi, method="ward.D2")
   library(factoextra)
   library(ggsci)
   require("ggsci")
   library(grDevices)
   require("grDevices")
   fviz_dend(x=myclust,cex = 0.8, lwd = 0.8, k = 5,
      k_colors = "jco",
      rect = TRUE, 
      rect_border = "jco", 
      rect_fill = TRUE,
      color_labels_by_k = TRUE,
      xlab="objectifs",
      main = "Cluster Dendrogram",)
```

this is a reproducible part of the the data which I've worked on it

```
> mydata<-read.csv("new.csv")
> head(mydata)
             Stop.Name                     Address        City State Postal.Code        Phone 
  X_Longitude Y_Latitude
 1                NK Supply                 327 3RD AVE Chula Vista    CA       91910 619-585-1267   
  -117.0794   32.64016
 2          Crown Equipment                333 BROADWAY Chula Vista    CA       91910 619-691-5312   
  -117.0915   32.63655
 3           Jack's Grocery         7712 UNIVERSITY AVE     La Mesa    CA       91941 619-466-6882   
  -117.0312   32.76189
 4    Myers Service Station 2010 JIMMY DURANTE BLVD 122     Del Mar    CA       92014 858-755-5232   
  -117.2652   32.96726
 5   Custom Art Supply Shop       7720 EL CAMINO REAL J    Carlsbad    CA       92009 760-632-1131   
  -117.2687   33.08707
 6 American Legion Post 444       7720 EL CAMINO REAL J    Carlsbad    CA       92009 760-944-8101   
  -117.2687   33.08707
```

Comment: I'm not quite following. You have an `hclust` object—you just want to make a data frame that includes the cluster assignments, then write out a csv? Most of your code and libraries you're loading are unrelated to that task—you don't need leaflet for anything here, and the question isn't actually about plotting. Keep in mind the *minimal* part of [mcve] and focus on the actual task at hand.

Comment: Additionally, `hclust` on its own doesn't assign clusters. You do that with `cutree`, which requires some decision-making on your part as to how you want to cut the tree. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46383790/5325862

Comment: yes camile I know that cutree is used to assign clusters but I chose to use  `fviz_dend` instead of it which make clusters more clear and well presented.

Comment: my real problem is when I got the clustering resuts how can I extract and export data which corresponding on each cluster in a "csv" file

Answer (score 0):

you can add the cluster to your rows, and then use a for loop. Assuming you add a column named "Cluster"

```
setDT(dt)
for(i in unique(dt$Cluster)){
dt[Cluster == i]
fwrite(dt, file = paste(i, ".csv", sep = "))
}
```